# Why does the browser show nothing when I use an image as a link

Tags: html

`

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
SPARK
</title>
</head>
<body>
<font face="Arial"><h1>
<center>SPARK Registration form</center>
</h1>
This is the registration form for the SPARK exam-2019.The student must belong to class 8 ,that is, 13-14 years of age.After filling the form you can click
the OK button to submit the form.
<form action="SPARK.html" method="post">
NAME :<input type="text" size="20">
<br><br>
CLASS :<input type="radio">8<br><br>
DIVISION :<br>:<input type="radio">A<br><br>
    :<input type="radio">B<br><br>
    :<input type="radio">C<br><br>
    :<input type="radio">D<br><br>
    :<input type="radio">E<br><br>
About you (Ambition)  :<input type="text" size ="100"> <br><br>
E-mail address :<input type="text" size="50">
<a href="G:\HTML STUDIES\rufsana.html"><img src="iex.jpg"  align="right">
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

`When I try to input an image link , the image doesn't appear.I searched wherever I could but I didn't get an answer to my question.If would be great if anyone helped me.

Comment: I just could use a image using a link

Comment: Can you give me more details?

Answer (score 3):

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         SPARK
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <font face="Arial">
      <h1>
         <center>SPARK Registration form</center>
      </h1>
      This is the registration form for the SPARK exam-2019.The student must belong to class 8 ,that is, 13-14 years of age.After filling the form you can click
      the OK button to submit the form.
      <form action="SPARK.html" method="post">
         NAME :<input type="text" size="20">
         <br><br>
         CLASS :<input type="radio">8<br><br>
         DIVISION :<br>:<input type="radio">A<br><br>
         :<input type="radio">B<br><br>
         :<input type="radio">C<br><br>
         :<input type="radio">D<br><br>
         :<input type="radio">E<br><br>
         About you (Ambition)  :<input type="text" size ="100"> <br><br>
         E-mail address :<input type="text" size="50">
         <a href="G:\HTML STUDIES\rufsana.html"><img src="https://mk0jobadderjftub56m0.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow.com-300.jpg"  align="right">
         </a>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I typed the </form> but it is not make any difference.I tried by giving the address of the image but it also dissapointed me.A slight correction : The picture is not seen but instead a cross is seen.What can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close your form. Insert `</form>` right above your anchor statement.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to add the following CSS to your HTML:

```
a{
   display: block;
}

a img{
   height: 50%;
   width: 50%;
}
/*
   Your height and width of the image depends on your requirement.
*/
```

And ofcourse, the `<form>` tag needs a closing tag `</form>`.